# Authentication for two projects running simultaneously

Tags: django, web-applications, localhost, port

I have two Django projects running simultaneously on localhost. One on port 8000 and the other 9000. When I log in on project 1, project 2 logs out and when I log in project 2, project 1 logs out. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

session conflict

Try

```
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'sessionid_yourproject'
```

adding in your setting